# What mistake am I doing while differentiating?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

If $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ are positive scalars and $a,\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\lambda_{3}$ are constant positive scalar values.
\begin{align}
x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+x_{3}^2+\lambda_{1}(x_{1}-a(x_{2}+x_{3}))+\lambda_{2}(x_{2}-a(x_{1}+x_{3}))+\lambda_{3}(x_{3}-a(x_{1}+x_{2}))\quad\quad\text{(1)}\\
\sum\limits_{n=1}^3 x_{n}^2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^3\lambda_{n}(x_{n}-a(\sum\limits_{a=1}^3 x_{a}-x_{n}))\quad\quad\text{(2)}
\end{align}
Differentiating 1 w.r.t $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ gives
\begin{align}
2 x_{1}+\lambda_{1}-a\lambda_{2}-a\lambda_{3}=0\quad\quad\text{(3)}\\
x_{1}=(-\lambda_{1}+a\lambda_{2}+a\lambda_{3})/2\quad\quad\text{(4)}
\end{align} 
Similarly
\begin{align}
x_{2}=(-\lambda_{2}+a\lambda_{1}+a\lambda_{3})/2\quad\quad\text{(5)}\\
x_{3}=(-\lambda_{3}+a\lambda_{1}+a\lambda_{2})/2\quad\quad\text{(6)}
\end{align} 
Or
\begin{align}
x_{n}=(-\lambda_{n}+a(\sum\limits_{a=1}^3\lambda_{a}-\lambda_{n}))/2\quad\quad\text{(7)}\\
\end{align} 
Differentiating 2 w.r.t $x_{n}$ gives
\begin{align}
2 x_{n}+\lambda_{n}-a(1-1)=0\quad\quad\text{(8)}\\
 x_{n}=-\lambda_{n}/2\quad\quad\text{(9)}
\end{align}
Are 1 and 2 equivalent?If yes, why differentiation of both doesn't return the same result( i.e (7)$\neq$(9)). Which basic rule of derivative am I forgetting while differentiating 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Differentiating 2 w.r.t $x_{n}$ gives
>   $$2 x_{n}+\lambda_{n}-a(1-1)=0\quad\quad\text{(8)}$$

Error here is that $x_n$ appears in *all* terms of the sum, but only gets differentiated in one of them. This is made more confusing by using $n$ as both the index of the sum *and* the variable being differentiated against. The correct derivative in $x_k$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}
\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^3 x_{n}^2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^3\lambda_{n}(x_{n}-a(\sum\limits_{a=1}^3 x_{a}-x_{n}))\right) &= 2 x_k + \lambda_k\left(1-a(1-1)\right) + \sum_{n=1, n \ne k}^3 \lambda_n\left(-a\right) \\ 
& = 2 x_k + \lambda_k - a\sum_{n=1, n \ne k}^3 \lambda_n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain a bit how are you differentiating the last part. I don't get how are you getting the summation over $\lambda$

Comment: @ZainAli You just break the second sum into the $n=k$ term plus the sum of all others terms where $n \ne k$.

Comment: @ZainAli  When $n \ne k$ the derivative is: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(\lambda_{n}(x_{n}-a(\sum\limits_{a=1}^3 x_{a}-x_{n}))\right) = \lambda_n(0 - a(1 -0))=-\lambda_n\,a$$